# i am trying to create a live candlestick chart with data from Intreractive Brokers TWS API, what am i doing wrong? I get the following error:

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws, ib-api

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = [] #Initialize variable to store candle

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f'Time: {bar.date} Open: {bar.open} High: {bar.high} Low: {bar.low} Close: {bar.close}')
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close])
        
    def realtimeBar(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f'Time: {bar.date} Open: {bar.open} High: {bar.high} Low: {bar.low} Close: {bar.close}')
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close])

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
contract.secType = 'STK'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.currency = 'USD'

#Request historical candles
app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, '', '2 D', '1 hour', 'BID', 0, 2, False, [])
    
#Create a dataframe from the historical data 
df = pd.DataFrame(app.data,columns=["date","open","high","low","close"]) 

data = pd.DataFrame()
data["date"] = df["date"]
data["open"] = df["open"]
data["high"] = df["high"]
data["low"] = df["low"]
data["close"] = df["close"]

#Plot the candlestick chart 
plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.title('AAPL Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.plot(df.index, df['open'], label='open')
plt.plot(df.index, df['high'], label='high')
plt.plot(df.index, df['low'], label='low')
plt.plot(df.index, df['close'], label='close')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Request Live Data Type
app.reqMarketDataType(4)
#Requesting the Live Market Data
app.reqRealTimeBars(1, contract, 1, "MIDPOINT", True, [])

#Create a dataframe from the real-time data 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(app.data,columns=["date","open","high","low","close"])

#Add the real-time data to the historical data 
if not df2.empty:
    df = df.append(df2)

print(df)

#Plot the live candlestick chart 
plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.title('AAPL Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.plot(df.index, df['open'], label='open')
plt.plot(df.index, df['high'], label='high')
plt.plot(df.index, df['low'], label='low')
plt.plot(df.index, df['close'], label='close')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the error is the following:

Reloaded modules: ibapi, ibapi.message, ibapi.enum_implem, ibapi.object_implem, ibapi.common, ibapi.utils, ibapi.contract, ibapi.softdollartier, ibapi.order, ibapi.order_state, ibapi.execution, ibapi.ticktype, ibapi.commission_report, ibapi.wrapper, ibapi.server_versions, ibapi.tag_value, ibapi.scanner, ibapi.errors, ibapi.comm, ibapi.order_condition, ibapi.orderdecoder, ibapi.decoder, ibapi.reader, ibapi.connection, ibapi.client
ERROR 1 504 Not connected
ERROR -1 504 Not connected
ERROR -1 504 Not connected
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, open, high, low, close]
Index: []

can anybody here help me debug it?

Comment: Your application can't talk to IB directly. You need to launch TWS, configure it to receive API commands, and then run your code. Your application will talk to IB through TWS.

Comment: Hi Matthew,yes I have TWS up and running with all the required API settings and I still get the error

Comment: When you call `app.connect`, set the last argument to 0 instead of 123. Will that work?

Comment: Yeah it works but the plot is empty, getting the data but there is no plot